# Attempting to upgrade a hosted Google AdSense account only redirects to home rather showing upgrade form

Tags: google-adsense

I want be straight about my question, I have a hosted google adsense account from youtube and I want to upgrade it to show ads on my website. I follow all the steps , Sign in > My ads > Other Products > Upgrade Now.

Problem : After the last step I am supposed to see a application form where I give my website url, but on clicking the upgrade now I am redirecting to adsense home page.

What I have done to resolve this issue.

1. I have tried this on different browsers.
2. I have tried this on different systems.
3. I have crossed 10$ threshold and have verified my address via PIN.
4. I have post this on adsense forum, nothing happens.
5. I try to make other account, but it didn't allow me to do as my
   details was same on new account and adsense do not allow multiple
   accounts.

What to do in that case?

(As most of the people are not getting my point so I made a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MFTNK8lQ0U&feature=youtu.be) to show what's actually going on in my account.)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google Adsense homepage.

After that login with the same email as of your YouTube and complete the Rest Process.

Comment: Watch this [video](https://youtu.be/-MFTNK8lQ0U) 
Sorry but the problem is comes up after logging in, when I clicked on `Upgrade Now`

Comment: One more thing I would tell that the url it shows, have **noaccount=false** 
thind, I don't know what it means, or maybe this is also related to the fault.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be following [the instructions that Google provides](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2534771?hl=en)

> To apply to show ads on your own site:
>
> 1. Sign in to your AdSense account.
> 2. Visit the My ads tab.
> 3. In the sidebar, click Other products.
> 4. Click Upgrade now and complete the application form.
> 5. ...

If that step is not working for you, there is likely a bug on Google's end that only they can fix.   You may be out of luck until they work on it.

In the Google Product Forums, [lots of people seem to be having problem with upgrading hosted accounts](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/adsense/upgrade$20hosted).
Based on these forums:

- Check that you are eligible to upgrade.
- Your account must have had at least $10 in revenue
- You must have verified your postal address by receiving a PIN in the mail from Google.    You can start this process from "Settings" -> "Account Information" -> "Verify Address"

You say that you have also tried multiple browsers.  Another thing to try would be a fresh browser profile with no extensions enabled.   Extensions such as AdBlock can sometimes prevent the AdSense website from working properly.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps :

1. Go to ---> youtube.com/account_monetization
2. Then ---> Asociated Adsense Account
3. Click Change

After that just give your domain and it will be good.